# Changing dashboard space

Tags: mission-control, dashboard

I realized the other day that I never use the dashboard and had no desire to. So I decided to disable it. But I feel as if the 3 finger swipe to the right that had displayed it is now wasted. Can something else fill that space?

Comment: Incomplete question !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always add more spaces by clicking the <kbd>+</kbd> button in the upper right when you swipe up:

[image]

Comment: Yes, but you still must always have a desktop on the far left side. What I'm shooting for in a centered desktop space. So I can swipe either way to get to my apps.

Comment: @AaronAAA that was not your original question so please EDIT